# Dynamics CRM Odata query filter by optionsetvalue

Tags: javascript, odata, microsoft-dynamics

How do I filter records by optionset value? I am trying like this:

```
 "$select=new_id&$filter=new_campaignid/Id eq guid'" + myId+ "' and new_optionsetfield eq '" + optionsetCode + "'"
```

But this does not work. I keep on getting bad request with error message:

```
Operator 'eq' incompatible with operand types 
'Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.ComplexTypeInstance`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]' 
and 'System.String' at position 96.
```

Comment: after searching for ... unfortunately hours... this question and the answer from @Wedge really saved my day in the end

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is what you need:

```
"$select=new_id&$filter=new_campaignid/Id eq guid'" + myId+ "' and new_optionsetfield/Value eq " + optionsetCode
```

Edited: Removed the quotes, because that is an int value, not a string

Here's an exact working sample:

```
AccountSet?$filter=CustomerTypeCode/Value eq 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately now I get this error: Operator 'eq' incompatible with operand types 'Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.ComplexTypeInstance`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]' and 'System.Int32' at position 96.

Comment: @cAMPy - must use `new_lookupfield/Id` and `new_optionsetfield/Value` to actually compare values of Lookups and OptionSets in the query (note the slash)

Answer (score 0):

One of my filters for Dynamics CRM 365 (on premise) looks like this

```
var filter = "(substringof('SomeStringValue', Description) eq false) and (StatusCode/Value ne 1)";
```